# Python: encode arbitrary object with json builtin

Tags: python, json

I am writing a webapp with a Tornado backend and, of course, javascript and jquery on the frontend, so I am using the builtin json module in the standard library to serialize objects for the frontend. I had started writing a custom JSONEncoder for my classes, but then it occurred to me that I could simply write a very simple, generic object encoder:

```
class ObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return vars(obj)
```

It seems to be working nicely, so I wondered why this is not included in the module, and if this technique has drawbacks. I didn't experiment if it works nicely with check_circular, but I have no reason to believe it doesn't.

Any comments on my doubts? Otherwise, I suppose this technique may be useful to somebody, since I didn't find it with a search (admittedly, a quick one).

EDIT: here's an example, as simple as it gets, to show the behaviour of the json module:

```
>>> import json
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.bar = 'bar'
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> json.dumps(foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f14660236d8> is not JSON serializable
>>> class ObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, obj):
...         return vars(obj)
... 
>>> json.dumps(foo, cls=ObjectEncoder)
'{"bar": "bar"}'
```

Comment: What's wrong with `json.dumps(obj)` ?

Comment: It raises `TypeError: <... instance at ...> is not JSON serializable`. This seems to be by design, since it is explicitly stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table), I would just like to understand why it is so, and if there are complication which I do not see.

Comment: Post the full error stacktrace please

Comment: I really don't see the point, anyway, here's a full example:

Comment: (added to the main post, it was too long for comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vars(obj)` is syntactic sugar for `obj.__dict__`, so it doesn't work on any object without `__dict__`. This includes stuff like:

1. User-defined objects where every level in the class hierarchy defined `__slots__` (without a `__dict__` slot) to reduce memory usage
2. Objects of built-in types that don't opt-in to a `tp_dict` slot

Worse, there are in-between cases, where some attributes are set on the `__dict__`, while others aren't (e.g. a class hierarchy where `__slots__` was used for some levels, but other levels didn't use `__slots__` and relied on the implicit `__dict__`). In cases like that, you wouldn't get an error to let you know something had gone wrong, you'd just serialize the `__dict__` part of the object state and silently ignore the rest.

You'd have similar problems if the interface uses `@property`s; they're used like attributes, but they're not on the instance `__dict__`, so you'd either lose the information completely (if there is no hidden underlying attribute), or serialize the "wrong" value (the internal name, rather than the API name exposed as an `@property`).

In short, lots of things can go subtly wrong by trying to guess at the correct behavior like this, which is why The Zen of Python (type `import this` in an interactive terminal to see it) includes stuff like:

> Errors should never pass silently.

and

> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

Beyond these errors, there's also the general problem of reversability. A general *encoder* of this form is definitionally incapable of being handled by a general *decoder* (because you lose all the type information). Offering an easy way to lose important information is... suboptimal.

Comment: I am sure I had thanked you, but my comment was lost :( 
Well, at least I had accepted your answer...

Comment: In fact, I had come back here to note that I had hit the first problem with my aproach: I needed a `set` in on of my classes, and _that_ hasn't got a `__dict__`, so I had to change approach: I use the `vars()` approach for a list of predefined user classes, and custom code for other classes like `set`.